Proper RGB888 to RGB565 conversion
I've found three RGB888 to RGB565 conversion algorithms, but I'm not sure which is the most correct.  The first two produce the same results.  The third produces a different result, but does agree with an online calculator.  And the third one makes sense, since it does scaling.  But the first two are going to be faster since there's no integer multiplication or division.
uint8_t r8, g8, b8;
uint16_t r5, g6, b5, val;

r8 = someredvalue;
g8 = somegreenvalue;
b8 = somebluevalue;


// first method:
b5 =  (b8  >> 3)        & 0x001F;
g6 = ((g8  >> 2) <<  5) & 0x07E0;
r5 = ((r8  >> 3) << 11) & 0xF800;
val = (r5 | g6 | b5);
printf("%d, %d, %d, %u\n", r8, g8, b8, val);


// second method:
val = ((r8 & 0b11111000) << 8) | ((g8 & 0b11111100) << 3) | (b8 >> 3);
printf("%d, %d, %d, %u\n", r8, g8, b8, val);


// third method:
r5 = r8 * 31 / 255;
g6 = g8 * 63 / 255;
b5 = b8 * 31 / 255;     
val =  (r5 << 11) | (g6 << 5) | (b5);
printf("%d, %d, %d, %u\n", r8, g8, b8, val);


The third method is slightly weird. When I first looked at it, I assumed r8 * 31 / 255 --> (r8 * 31) >> 8. But, this would need: r8 * 31 / 256 (and the optimizer would probably convert the division into the shift).

If you can't see the difference, it probably doesn't matter.  All 3 methods will be mostly the same.

@CraigEstey I agree that method #3 looks weird, but it appears to be scaling the values.  The other methods are simply dropping the lower bits without scaling.

Scaling seems like it would be a better option, but it's not.  To get the top value in your output (e.g. 31 for r), only 255 in the input will scale to it.  Those top values will be severely underrepresented in the output.

Both 255 and 256 do scaling. 256 lets us do the shift (which is faster). Without thinking too much, I'd guess that 255 is an attempt at rounding (vs truncation)??? But, when doing this for realtime conversion (of video), I'd opt for speed as the slight variation probably won't be noticed by a viewer. Remember, we're taking 24 bits of accuracy per pixel and squishing it down to 16. A "true" algorithm might convert to YCbCr, scale truncate there and convert back (preserving the luma which is the most noticeable). But, I hardly think it's worth it.

So the choice is either of the first two methods?

I just timed them all and method #1 come out the fastest.  #1: 20040, #2: 21375, #3: 42585.  Values in microseconds.

Having done video scaling in a professional/commercial R/T product, you could do A/B testing. Try several video clips. Convert with method 1, 2. It helps to have two monitors (or some tiny embedded displays?) side-by-side displaying the same video data. Which "looks better"? For true A/B testing, several people vote as this is a subjective test.

I'd rerun the benchmarks. A disassembly (x86) of meth 2 is one fewer instructions (vs meth 1). Also, meth 3 generates only multiplies (no division). And, changing 255 to 256 does no multiplies (only shifting).

@CraigEstey I ran the test several times, same results.  The code runs on a RPi Pico.  I would have thought method #2 was the fastest as well; surprised that #1 was.


The first two produce the same results.

Because they are equivalent, at least for compilers that support 0bxxx-style binary constants, which is an extension to standard C.  Both take the color values of the 565 format as the correct number of the most significant bits of the corresponding color value in the 888 format.

The third produces a different result, but does agree with an online calculator.
And the third one makes sense, since it does scaling.

They all do scaling.  The third one just uses slightly different scale factors than the others do.
Consider the red channel.  Five bits can represent values from 0 to 31.  Eight bits can represent values from 0 to 255.  Mathematically, the factor for scaling linearly from the latter range to the former is 31 / 255, as the third approach uses.  The other two are dividing by 8 (via shift), which is the same arithmetically as scaling by 32 / 256.  Those are not the same scale factor, of course, but they are close.
But before you take method 3 to be more correct, you should consider the effects of integer arithmetic.  For example, which 8-bit red values map to 31 in 5-bit representation?  With method 3, only one does: 255.  Value 254 scales to slightly less than 31, which is truncated to 30.  This variation on the conversion is thus non-uniform with respect to how many RGB888 colors corespond to each RGB565 color.
The bit-shifting approach, on the other hand, is uniform in this sense.  When converting this way, each RGB565 color corresponds to the same number (256) of RGB888 colors.

I'm not sure which is the most correct.

Overall, the two rescalings produce very similar results, within 1 unit per channel of each other.  Both are linear, up to truncation to integer.  Neither is more correct than the other in an absolute sense.  The bit-shifting alternatives are distinguished by distributing the results uniformly over the RGB565 space.  The other alternative is distinguished by mapping only maximum RGB888 intensities to maximum RGB565 intensities.  There might also be a performance difference, but if that's important to you then you should measure.  For most purposes, I would be inclined to choose the uniformity of one of the bit-shifting approaches, but you may think differently.

BTW: C23 defines the 0b... "extension". See C23 6.4.4.1

Very good, @pmg, if only C23, or C2X by any other name, were yet adopted.  That may come Real Soon Now, but at this time, standard C is still C17.

I tested all the combinations with algorithm 1 and 3, and they were always within 1 of each other.  But almost 7 times more were not equal than were equal.  I'd consider that a significant difference.  I agree that the bit-shifting alternatives are the best.

I suppose how significant the difference between 1 and 3 is depends on your purposes, @MarkRansom.  If it's judged by how noticeable such differences are to the human eye, then I'm inclined to think that the significance is indeed small.  They are within the range of normal human perception, but the differences would be subtle.  Variations in the presentation medium can produce much larger differences than that.

Remember that the diminished scale of RGB565 will make those differences more apparent - a difference of 1 becomes a difference of 8 if you expand back to RGB888.  The more significant issue though is missing all those top values.  To get correct scaling you should multiply by n+1 and divide by m+1, which is what the bit shifting is doing implicitly.


@CraigEstey I ran the test several times, same results. The code runs on a RPi Pico. I would have thought method #2 was the fastest as well; surprised that #1 was. –
Mike

Hmm ... I was running the tests on an older x86 PC (don't have an RPi). Still ...

I get method 2 is the fastest (with gcc)
But, m1 is faster with clang. But, this is because it used loop unrolled x86 SIMD instructions.

So that we're on common ground (just for fun), I've enclosed my full benchmark program for your algorithms.

Here is the test program (all.c):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#if USE_BYTE_ARG
typedef unsigned char arg_t;
#else
typedef unsigned int arg_t;
#endif

typedef unsigned short u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned int u32;

#ifndef MAX_Y
#define MAX_Y   1080
#endif

#ifndef MAX_X
#define MAX_X   1920
#endif

u8 bigbuf_888[MAX_Y * MAX_X * 3];
u16 bigbuf_565[MAX_Y * MAX_X];

#define inline_always static inline __attribute__((always_inline))

inline_always u32
m1(arg_t r8,arg_t g8,arg_t b8)
{
    u32 b5 = (b8 >> 3) & 0x001F;
    u32 g6 = ((g8 >> 2) << 5) & 0x07E0;
    u32 r5 = ((r8 >> 3) << 11) & 0xF800;
    u32 val = (r5 | g6 | b5);
    return val;
}

inline_always u32
m2(arg_t r8,arg_t g8,arg_t b8)
{
    u32 val = ((r8 & 0b11111000) << 8) | ((g8 & 0b11111100) << 3) | (b8 >> 3);
    return val;
}

inline_always u32
m3(arg_t r8,arg_t g8,arg_t b8)
{
    u32 r5 = r8 * 31 / 255;
    u32 g6 = g8 * 63 / 255;
    u32 b5 = b8 * 31 / 255;
    u32 val = (r5 << 11) | (g6 << 5) | (b5);
    return val;
}

inline_always u32
m4(arg_t r8,arg_t g8,arg_t b8)
{
    u32 r5 = (r8 * 31) / 256;
    u32 g6 = (g8 * 63) / 256;
    u32 b5 = (b8 * 31) / 256;
    u32 val = (r5 << 11) | (g6 << 5) | (b5);
    return val;
}

#define CAT(_a,_b) \
    _a##_b
#define DOTEST(_m) \
    CAT(dotest_,_m)

#define M   m1
#include "test.c"

#define M   m2
#include "test.c"

#define M   m3
#include "test.c"

#define M   m4
#include "test.c"

typedef struct tst {
    void (*tst_fnc)(u16 *dst,const u8 *src,u32 count);
    const char *tst_sym;
    double tst_elap;
} tst_t;

#define DEFTST(_sym) \
    { .tst_fnc = dotest_##_sym, .tst_sym = #_sym }

tst_t tstlist[] = {
    DEFTST(m1),
    DEFTST(m2),
    DEFTST(m3),
    DEFTST(m4),
};

#define FORALL \
    tst_t *tst = tstlist;  tst < &tstlist[countof(tstlist)];  ++tst

#define countof(_arr) \
    sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0])

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void
dotest(tst_t *tst)
{

    tst->tst_elap = 1e9;

    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 10;  ++iter) {
        double tscbeg = tscgetf();
        tst->tst_fnc(bigbuf_565,bigbuf_888,MAX_Y * MAX_X);
        double tscend = tscgetf();

        tscend -= tscbeg;
        if (tscend < tst->tst_elap)
            tst->tst_elap = tscend;
    }

#if 0
    printf("%.9f %s\n",tst->tst_elap,tst->tst_sym);
#endif
}

int
tstcmp(const void *alhs,const void *arhs)
{
    const tst_t *lhs = alhs;
    const tst_t *rhs = arhs;
    int cmp;

    do {
        cmp = -1;
        if (lhs->tst_elap < rhs->tst_elap)
            break;

        cmp = 1;
        if (lhs->tst_elap > rhs->tst_elap)
            break;

        cmp = 0;
    } while (0);

    return cmp;
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("%ux%u\n",MAX_X,MAX_Y);

    for (FORALL)
        dotest(tst);

    qsort(tstlist,countof(tstlist),sizeof(tst_t),tstcmp);

    tst_t *otst = tstlist;
    for (FORALL) {
        printf("%.9f %s (%.3fx slower than %s)\n",
            tst->tst_elap,tst->tst_sym,
            tst->tst_elap / otst->tst_elap,otst->tst_sym);
#if 0
        otst = tst;
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}


Here is the test.c it needs (must be a separate file):
void
DOTEST(M)(u16 *rgb565,const u8 *rgb888,u32 count)
{

    for (u32 idx = 0;  idx < count;  idx += 1, rgb888 += 3)
        rgb565[idx] = M(rgb888[0],rgb888[1],rgb888[2]);
}

#undef M


Compiled with gcc 8.3.1:
gcc -Wall -O3 -o all all.c

The output is:
1920x1080
0.003618755 m2 (1.000x slower than m2)
0.003766094 m1 (1.041x slower than m2)
0.005401992 m4 (1.493x slower than m2)
0.007230262 m3 (1.998x slower than m2)


Compiled with clang 7.0.1:
clang -Wall -O3 -o all all.c

The output:
1920x1080
0.002214470 m1 (1.000x slower than m1)
0.002892669 m2 (1.306x slower than m1)
0.005501939 m4 (2.485x slower than m1)
0.007757501 m3 (3.503x slower than m1)


Thanks for doing that.  The issue with the RPi Pico may be that I program using RPi's SDK for the Pico, so there's a layer out of my control unless I decide to program "bare metal".

While reasonable people might disagree about the proper way to convert RGB888 -> RGB565, everybody pretty much agrees about the proper way to convert RGB565 -> RGB888:
r8 = (r5*33) >> 2;

This just populates the top bits of r8 with r5, and then fills the remaining bits with the most significant bits of r5.  Some might use a rounding division instead of a simple bit shift.  The difference isn't significant.
So for each value in r5, there is an unambiguous corresponding value in r8.  When converting r8 back to r5, I prefer to select the closest of those values and convert to the corresponding value in r5.
Your method 3 almost does this, but you should round the divisions:
r5 = (r8 * 31 + 127) / 255;
g6 = (g8 * 63 + 127) / 255;
b5 = (b8 * 31 + 127) / 255;


Sorry, your modification to the multiply/divide has the same problem as the original.  The inputs are not uniformly distributed to the outputs, except that instead of all the error being in the highest value you've used rounding to split the error between the lowest and highest.  Go through all the inputs of 0 to 255 and count how many end up in each output.

@MarkRansom It's not a problem, objectively.  You just don't like it.

It's not a matter of liking or not liking - it IS objectively wrong.

no, it's not.  An even distribution into RGB565 buckets is a requirement you just made up.  If you make up a more reasonable requirement like that the change in the displayed color is as small as possible, then my way works better.
